# Deploy H2O Wave application to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, h2o, h2o.ai, h2o-wave

I am relatively new to deploying python web applications but I was trying to deploy my H2O wave app to Heroku but kept running into issues and I couldn't find much help in the documentation.

Everything works fine locally if I start the server using the command (in the SDK for wave):

```
$ ./waved
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # 
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # ┌─────────────────────────┐
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # │  ┌    ┌ ┌──┐ ┌  ┌ ┌──┐  │ H2O Wave
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # │  │ ┌──┘ │──│ │  │ └┐    │ 0.11.0 20210118061246
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # │  └─┘    ┘  ┘ └──┘  └─┘  │ © 2020 H2O.ai, Inc.
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # └─────────────────────────┘
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # 
2021/01/22 10:26:38 # {"address":":10101","t":"listen","webroot":"/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/TTT/H2O Wave/wave/www"}
2021/01/22 10:26:39 # {"addr":"127.0.0.1:64065","route":"/tennis-pred","t":"ui_add"}
2021/01/22 10:46:04 # {"host":"http://127.0.0.1:8000","route":"/counter","t":"app_add"}
```

then in the root directory of the project running:

```
uvicorn tennis_pred_app:main
```

For deployment, all I have other than my wave python file is a `requirements.txt` and a `Procfile`:

```
web: uvicorn tennis_pred_app:main --host 0.0.0.0 --port 10101
```

this is what my foo (tennis_pred_app.py) looks like (simplified):

```
from h2o_wave import Q, main, app, ui

@app("/tennis-pred")
async def serve(q: Q):
    show_form(q)
    await q.page.save()
```

The error I am currently running into is:

```
2021-01-22T00:28:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user x
2021-01-22T00:31:07.040695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-22T00:31:06.879674+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1dc65130 by user x
2021-01-22T00:31:06.879674+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user x
2021-01-22T00:31:26.580199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `uvicorn tennis_pred_app:main --host 0.0.0.0 --port 20819`
2021-01-22T00:31:30.299421+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:20819 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2021-01-22T00:31:30.299892+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:     Started parent process [4]
2021-01-22T00:31:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-22T00:32:27.041954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-01-22T00:32:27.093099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-01-22T00:32:27.199933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-01-22T00:32:27.242769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: This is weird. Your logs say "Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:33594", which I'd guess is the right port as it changes every time, but it also says your app isn't binding to the port.

Comment: Yes, it is weird since it is working fine on the localhost, and the only thing I've added is the Procfile

Comment: Can you show your `foo.py`, please?

Comment: Your `Procfile` says `foo:main`. You say your `foo.py` is actually `tennis_pred_app.py`. The code snippet you showed has just one function: `serve`. So does your `Procfile` _actually_ say `web: uvicorn tennis_pred_app:serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT`?

Comment: Yes, I have used tennis_pred_app instead of foo and I had main instead of serve because of the documentation from the H2O wave website: https://h2oai.github.io/wave/docs/deployment and main and Q are both things I imported from the h2o_wave library (edited the above post again)

Answer (score 3):

You don't get to choose your port on Heroku. Instead, [Heroku assigns you a port via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers).

Change your `Procfile` from

```
web: uvicorn foo:main --host 0.0.0.0 --port 10101
```

to

```
web: uvicorn foo:main --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, however even after making this change I am still getting the same error, do you have any more ideas? (I have added an image of the full error above)

Comment: You're still getting a boot timeout with an error that your process isn't binding to `$PORT`? That exact error message?

Comment: What is the reason why it needs to listen to a port?

Comment: Because that's how servers work. They listen for connections on (usually one) port.

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention is that when I run locally, I need to start the server first by executing a ./waved command in the SDK package for wave, would I need to include this in my deployment as well?

Comment: don't mean to bother but could you take a look at this question? Same problem but I reworded it which may make it simpler to understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888300/deploy-python-based-web-application-to-heroku

Answer (score 0):

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@srini.x/deploy-your-wave-app-in-5-minutes-bd440d00917f) for the exact guide.

More explanation for why the other answer is generally correct but does not apply to H2O Wave:

If you look at [architecture](https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/architecture), you may notice there are actually 2 servers included. The first is a python (uvicorn) one that is used for your Wave app - this is not exposed to the outside directly but uses a kind of a proxy server - the second server. This second (Golang) server communicates directly with a browser (outside) and thus should be started on the `$PORT` Heroku assigned to you, e.g. via the `H2O_WAVE_LISTEN` env variable - see [other config options](https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/configuration/).