# How do I deploy my H2O wave app (e.g. with heroku)?

Tags: h2o-wave

Is there a way to deploy an app created using H2O wave?

I recently made a data visualization app and would like people to be able to demo it really quickly and easily.

I have tried following this thread: [Deploy H2O Wave application to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836484/deploy-h2o-wave-application-to-heroku) but the problem seems to be unresolved thru previous replies.

In addition, H2O's docs (https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/deployment) don't really explain this in much detail. Not many articles about this exist elsewhere, so any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

H2O Wave maintainer here. You can see [this](https://medium.com/@srini.x/deploy-your-wave-app-in-5-minutes-bd440d00917f) or [this](https://mathanrajsharma.medium.com/how-to-deploy-h2o-wave-app-on-heroku-2abe2240731c) blog post on how to do it on Heroku specifically.

The deployment is no different from deploying any other server/software in general. All you need is a dedicated server (e.g. Heroku/AWS EC2) to which you upload your code, start the server, make sure the correct ports are exposed etc. If that sounds like too much work, I would recommend having a look at [enterprise - appstore solution](https://h2oai.github.io/h2o-ai-cloud/docs/introduction).